# IOS7 minimal ui not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, ios7

I want to hide url bar on IOS 7, so when I put `<meta name="viewport" content="minimal-ui">`, it  don't hide url bar, its still on the page and my website is not loaded responsive , its opened like its desktop version, does anyone knows why is this happening and how to do this properly?

I even tried

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    // Set a timeout...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar!
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

I read this article and it looks like its not possible on new IOS. [Link](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review)

Answer (score 1):

Note that (as of now) minimal-ui only works on iPhone, not iPad.

Make sure your meta tag is hard coded on the page (or rendered server side).

Try adding a fuller list of attributes. I have the following and it's working across iPhone 4 and 5 with iOS 7.1

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
```